# MS Excel & MS Share point - Data inconsistency during file upload (Solution: Problem solved when filename was renamed) Interested in RCA

Tags: sharepoint-online

Recently one of my co-workers observed a data discrepancy issue while uploading a MS Excel Workbook in Share point. To illustrate further, we observed that there is a column which computes summation of two column totals and displays the result. So, suppose if the total of column A is 20 and total of column B is 10, the final total at the end of the data sets (summary) which was supposed to display 20 + 10 = 30 is showing something else say 49, when it is getting uploaded in a shared folder in the Share point. However, when the xlsx file was opened in local drive, this computed column gave accurate results. And so, it did when we uploaded the file name as a different file name in the Share Point. We were eventually able to resolve the issue or data discrepancy by renaming the file to something else, but wondering why would that be a reason for the same. If anyone wants to dive deep and figure out the root cause of the issue or help us analyze this case for later, will be highly appreciated.

I did save the file as something else example file a.xlsx as a_v1.xlsx and the issue was resolved after uploading in Share Point. However, retaining the file name as a.xlsx was important for the team as a part of standard practice. So, any alternate solution or RCA would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear that this is a programming question. Please edit to include all relevant details (a [mcve]). Also, based on your title, it appears that you solved your issue? Please don't mention any details of a solution in your title or your question - that's what *answers* are for. And if this is, indeed, solved, it's unclear what you're asking.